# Does the address execute behind it or before?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel

I'm sorry I don't know how to ask this, but let me see if I can draw this out. I have this program:

```
section .data
    s1 db "nice",10,0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, s1
    call _print
    call _exit


_print:
    push rax 
    mov rbx, 0
_printLoop:
    inc rax 
    inc rbx 
    mov cl, [rax]
    cmp cl, 0
    jne _printLoop

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    pop rsi 
    mov rdx, rbx 
    syscall
    ret 

_exit:
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Which has a sub routine _print that will print some null terminated string with address stored in rax. My question is, I'm assuming that if I have a pointer to some string in memory (like s1), then it would look something like this:

```
rax
s1
 |
[n][i][c][e][\n][\0]
```

So, in my head, I would want to check what's stored in s1 to make sure the first character (the 'n' in "nice") is not the null terminator. But that's not how this program works. It increments rax and rbx(rbx storing the count) and first checks at s1+1, like so:

```
s1 rax
 |  |
[n][i][c][e][\n][\0]
```

So the only explanation I can think of, is that the s1 pointer either, at the start, points BEFORE the bytes that were allocated for the string, like this:

```
s1
|
[][n][i][c][e][\n][\0]
```

, or that when reading from it, it reads backwards, not forwards. But I'm not sure how it works. I hope I'm being clear enough for someone to clear this up for me. Thanks. This x86-64

Comment: Can you elaborate? It doesn't seem like the first character is getting compared

Comment: So for a fact, the "n" is not getting compared?

Comment: Ok so the algorithm just assumes the first character is fine. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @Michael, with that suggested change, it would compute the wrong length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as written gets the length right, as long as the string has at least one character. (That is a reasonable assumption, since what would be the point of printing a string with no characters, but unfortunately it is not robust.)

One easy way to fix it to properly handle an empty string would be this:

```
_print:
    mov rsi, rax
    mov rbx, 0

    cmp byte [rax], 0
    jz  _printSkip

_printLoop:
    inc rax
    inc rbx
    mov cl, [rax]
    cmp cl, 0
    jne _printLoop

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rdx, rbx
    syscall

_printSkip:
    ret
```

In addition to adding the check for an empty string before the loop, I changed it to put the pointer to the string directly into rsi instead of on the stack. By not using the stack to save rax, it avoids needing stack cleanup in the case where it skips the syscall.

Answer (score 0):

In my other answer, I made as few changes as possible to clearly show the changes needed to fix the problem. In this answer, I show how I would actually write it:

```
_print:
    cmp byte [rax], 0
    jz  _printSkip

    mov rsi, rax
    xor edx, edx
_printLoop:
    inc edx
    cmp byte [rsi+rdx], 0
    jnz _printLoop

    mov eax, 1
    mov edi, 1
    syscall

_printSkip:
    ret
```